# Mysql join query doesn't work for many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables called

- _partnership,
- _partners,
- _partnership_arm._partners = stores basic partner information
- _partnership_arm = stores partnership arm details
- _partnership = stores partners partnership records which includes the partner_id
- arm_id which reference _partners.partner_id and _partnership_arm.arm_id.

So as an admin i want to select all details from the _partnership table which join other table reference without a where clause, but am having issue doing it.
here is my code

```
SELECT 
    _partnership.*,
    _partners.names,
    _partnership_arm.arm_name
FROM
    `_partnership` 
JOIN
    `_partners`,`_partnership_arm` ON
       _partnership.partner_id = _partners.partner_id 
AND 
    _partnership.arm_id = _partnership_arm.arm_id
```

I also want a user to be able to select using a where clause
Please how can i achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the question or problem? The one thing i see wrong in your query is the `JOIN`. Rewrite it to be something like `FROM cec_partnership ps JOIN _partners p ON p.partner_id = ps.partner_id JOIN _partnership_arm pa ON ps.arm_id = pa.arm_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    _partnership.*,
    _partners.names,
    _partnership_arm.arm_name
FROM
    `_partnership` 
JOIN
    `_partners` ON _partnership.partner_id = _partners.partner_id
JOIN 
    `_partnership_arm` ON _partnership.arm_id = _partnership_arm.arm_id
```

Comment: Once i add parenthesis, i get an error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON (_partnership.partner_id = _partners.partner_id and _partnership.arm' at line 1

Comment: I have not noticed there were two joins, please try the query I have updated my answer with.

Comment: Thanks it worked, i didnt have idea that join can be used several times. Thank you